# how to launch file from computer B to execute in computer A

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-hydro, multiple-machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am running some navigation test with a mobile robot (A) with Ubuntu 12.04.1 and ROS hydro. I also have ROS on my laptop (B) and want to communicate both computers to launch the different nodes from my laptop.

Both computers are in the same network and using the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP I am able to see the nodes of the robot in my computer.
roscore is running in the robot and i have a launch file in the robot that launches different nodes, what i want is to call that launch file from my laptop (the computations and everything will execute in the robot but i want to call it from the laptop)

Is it needed to create a package in the laptop just to call the launch file or is there any other way ?

Sorry for my English, and thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362905/how-to-launch-file-from-computer-b-to-execute-in-computer-a/) by [lfvm0001](https://answers.ros.org/users/59247/lfvm0001/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-10-06**:
Is SSH not enough?

You cannot directly call a launch file on another machine, but you could use the `machine` tag to launch the nodes on the other computer: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine

**Comment by [lfvm0001](https://answers.ros.org/users/59247/lfvm0001/) on 2020-10-07**:
Thanks... if I use the machine tag , and I have some nodes that need some .yaml files, those files need to be in the computer where I’m launching the file right ? Even if the node is running in the other machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to **mgruhler** for the response! As he commented, what I want (to directly call a launch file from another computer) was not possible. However as recommended I use the tag machine in my launch file to tell to all the nodes to run in computer A and then run the file from computer B. And it’s working as intended.
Thanks

---

Originally posted by [lfvm0001](https://answers.ros.org/users/59247/lfvm0001/) with karma: 3 on 2020-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0